# Nicht-elektronische "Platine"

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology

Ein Joghurtbecher konfrontierte mich mit der Aufschrift:

> mindestens haltbar bis: siehe Platine.

ein Wort, das für mich bisher eine elektronische Leiterplatte bezeichnet hat.

Nun kann man auf der Begriffsklärungsseite von [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platine) nachlesen, dass damit der (bereits dem Recycling zugeführte) Aludeckel gemeint sein könnte. Duden und DWDS halten sich aber mit einer passenden Definition zurück. Ist das reine Fachsprache der Verpackungsindustrie oder sollte es nicht besser *Siegelplatine* heißen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Platine", aber auch "Siegelplatine" für den Deckel eines Joghurtbechers wären doch sehr verpacktungstechnisch-fachsprachliche Ausdrücke. Kein Mensch sagt das im Alltag. Folglich ist es auch in Schrifttextgattungen, die der Alltagssprache folgen, unangebracht. Dies gilt für Gattungen der Belletristik und des Journalismus, sowie in allen Texten, die sich mit dem Ziel, verständlich zu sein, an die Allgemeinheit wenden.

Besser hätte der Joghurthersteller auf seine Becher schreiben lassen:

> Mindestens haltbar bis: siehe Deckel
>
> Mindestens haltbar bis: siehe Deckelfolie
>
> Mindestens haltbar bis: siehe Verschlussfolie
>
> Mindestens haltbar bis: siehe Verschluss
>
> Mindestens haltbar bis: siehe oben

In einer Fachzeitschrift der Verpackungsindustrie und in Prospekten auf einer Lebensmittelmaschinenmesse mag man dagegen gerne von "Siegelplatinen" sprechen, wie ja auch Jäger unter sich den Schwanz des Hasen "Blume" nennen.

Answer (score 3):

Auf der Website von entsprechenden Herstellern findet man als Definition von

> Siegelplatine

"Siegelplatinen werden bevorzugt als Verschluss für Milchprodukte, Desserts und eine Vielzahl weiterer Produkte eingesetzt, die in Bechern abgefüllt werden."

Somit handelt es sich bei der Aufschrift auf dem Joghurtbecher vermutlich um eine Verkürzung des Fachbegriffs aus der Verpackungsindustrie.

Allerdings ist damit nicht (nur) - wie vom OP vermutet - der dem Recycling zugeführte Aludeckel gemeint, sondern durchaus auch der fabrikneue Deckel, der erst beim eigentlichen Hersteller auf dem gefüllten Becher angebracht wird.